# Apache 2.4.x Bandwidth Quota / Throttle / Speed

Tags: apache2, apache2-module

I'm looking for a new Apache 2.4.x module or solution which allows me to configure Bandwidth Quota's. Long ago I use mod_throttle which only works for 1.3 and is since no longer maintained. I've also been using mod_cband which I've patched to work with Apache 2.4 and it seems to be doing the job but I'm worried about future Apache upgrades could cause this software to become extinct as well. It also appears mod_cband is no longer maintained either.

I've looked at mod_bandwidth but that only appears to work for 1.3.x and mod_ratelimit doesn't exactly do what I'm looking for.

Specifically I'm looking for a way to set a max quota for each virtualhost and when that limit is reached either the connection is slowed down OR an error is displayed. Quota should be configured to automagically reset itself based on a pre-defined key, IE: 30 days, 2 hours, etc...

Any guidance would be nice. Paid software is ok for me too, long as I can demo it. Opensource solution would be best, of course =)

I should add, this should be for Unix/Linux, not Windows!

Answer (score -2):

Try using this
 http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband 
manges banwidth and qouta + works on linux

Comment: Perhaps you did not read my initial post. I've clearly already stated that I am using mod_cband and that I've patched it to work with Apache 2.4 since by default it does not work with the 2.4 tree.